# Making a JAR file which includes all files of a cetain type from any subdirectory

Tags: java, command-line, jar

So this is a simplified version of my package structure

```
 Project 1
 -folder1
 -folder2
  -folder21
   -folder211
    -test3.java
  -folder22
 -folder3
  -test4.java

-Project2
 -folder1
  -folder11
   -folder111
     -Test.java
 -folder2
  -.properties
  -Test2.java
 -folder3
```

What I want to find is command that will create a jar and take the paths to project1 and project2 and recursively add the folder structure and java files without adding the .properties files.

What i've tried so far is
jar cvf test.jar "pathtoproject1/*.java" "pathtoproject2/*.java"
That only works for java files in the base project directories not the subfolders.
Anyone know how to do this?

**edit**
This is for a batch script on windows

Comment: Do you want to do that in an ant script/batch script/programmatically? On which OS?

Comment: What platform are you on.  I ask because linux/unix varieties have a richer command line toolset IMHO

Comment: I am making a batch on windows

Comment: I'd use [WSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) instead, it's much more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly I'm not sure that jar handles this out of the box.

I suggest using ant - with an [ant jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html), using a [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).